# Ganeti command to find out how many more instances of a particular type fit into the cluster

Tags: capacity-planning, ganeti

I've once used a ganeti command to get the maximum number of instances of a particular type that fit into the cluster. Like this:

```
gnt-something how-many-more INSTANCE_TYPE
```

I was going through the manual and checked the man pages of all gnt commands but I don't remember this command nor can I find it again. Can someone help me?

Btw, this is the ganeti version:

```
Software version: 2.15.2
Internode protocol: 2150000
Configuration format: 2150000
OS api version: 20
Export interface: 0
VCS version: (ganeti) version v2.14.2-177-g003cd9a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody else is looking for this, the program is called `hspace`

The most trivial invocation would be:

```
hspace -m ganeti.myorg.net # (-m API_ENDPOINT)
```